Stress-Energy Tensor of perfect fluid in rest frame
The stress energy tensor $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the flux of momentum $p^\mu$ across a surface of constant $x^\nu$.
At the book I was reading, along with the wikipedia page, the stress-energy-tensor at the rest frame of a perfect fluid should look like:
$$
T^{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
\rho & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & p & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & p & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & p\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
But, shouldn't $T^{\mu\nu}$ be like this for a perfect fluid:
$$
T^{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
\rho & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -p & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -p & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -p\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$
For example, by above definition $T^{11}$ is the flux of x-momentum across a surface of constant $x$, which means:
$$T^{11} = \frac{p_1}{\Delta t\Delta y\Delta z}\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf{\hat x} = \frac{F_x}{A}\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf{\hat x}$$
Therefore:

if $x>0$ and $F>0$, means $T^{11} > 0$.
if $x < 0$ and $F < 0$, then $T^{11} > 0$.

Thus, $T^{11} > 0$, it means, we are pulling the object, instead of compressing it. Thus, positive pressure is when $T^{11} < 0$. In other words, I am saying it should be $p = -T^{11}$.
